# Creating Relationship Class- Adding new records to table

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, relationship-class, arcgis-10.6

I am creating a relationship class inside an SDE Environment (SQL Server 2016).

I have a point feature class and a related table.

I am trying to add rows to the currently empty table based off specific features from my point feature class.

the only way I see to do this is start an edit session, select all my points and open the attribute editor window then select the feature, use the drop down, right click the table and select "add new".

I have several thousands points I need to do this for, is there a bulk option or a way to automate this process? 
[image]

My keys in the origin table is GlobalID, the key field in destination table is a GUID field type named "Parent_GUID"

Comment: Populate original with relevant key and append related table.

Comment: can you expand on this, not sure what you mean

Comment: What are the names and types of keys in relationship? I can post solution using them, that will work in fgdb, no experience with sde though.

Comment: I edited my original question to answer your latest inquiry @FelixIP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original tables:

[image]

Table to be appended to FLOORS:

[image]

Add fields from FLOORS to fromEXCEL table:

[image]

and populate newly added fields:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("fromExcel", "FLOOR_DESCRIPTION", "[FLOOR]")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("fromExcel", "BUILDING_ID","[BUILDING]")
arcpy.AddJoin_management("fromExcel", "BUILDING", "BUILDINGS", "GISBUILDING","KEEP_ALL")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("fromExcel", "fromExcel.Parent_GUID", "[BUILDINGS.GlobalID]")
```

Remove join and original fields to make schemas between fromEXCEL and FLOORS match:

```
arcpy.DeleteField_management("fromExcel", "BUILDING;FLOOR")
```

and append fromEXCEL to FLOORS:

```
arcpy.Append_management("fromExcel", "FLOORS", schema_type="TEST")
```

Spot check:

[image]